# Why are my React rendered HTML elements changing positions after refresh?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-redux

I have a react component that I am using as checkpoint to check if the user has viewed a certain section of the site.

```
class ContentSection extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 }

render() {
const allParagraphs = [];

for (let i = 0; i < this.props.paragraphs.length; i++) {
  let p = this.props.paragraphs[i];

  allParagraphs.push(
    <Paragraph key={i} image={p["img"]} text={p["text"]} />
  );
}

return (
  <div className="cs">
    <ContentSectionCheckPointContainer
      uniqueIndex={this.props.uniqueIndex}
    />
    <h4 className="sectionTitle">THIS IS A SECTION!!!</h4>
    {allParagraphs}
  </div>
  );
 }
}
```

And this is the ContentSectionCheckPointContainer

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
 return {
  unlock: index => dispatch(Unlock_Index_Action(index))
  };
 };

const mapStateToProps = state => {
 return {
  CheckPoints: [...state.CheckPoints]
 };
};

class ContentSectionCheckPoint extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.myRect = null;
    this.checkVisibility = this.checkVisibility.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkVisibility();
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.checkVisibility);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.checkVisibility);
  }

  checkVisibility() {
    if (this.myRef.current) {
      let rect = this.myRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      var viewHeight = Math.max(
        document.documentElement.clientHeight,
        window.innerHeight
      );
      let b = !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top - viewHeight >= 0);
      if (b !== this.props.CheckPoints[this.props.uniqueIndex]) {
        if (b) {
          this.props.unlock(this.props.uniqueIndex);
        }else{
          this.props.unlock(this.props.uniqueIndex);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
this.checkVisibility();
    return (
      <div ref={this.myRef} className="cscp">
        {this.props.CheckPoints[this.props.uniqueIndex] && <p>hi</p>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const ContentSectionCheckPointContainer = connect(
mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ContentSectionCheckPoint);
```

As you can see I ran a visibility check on scroll, which works fine. However, I wanted to also run the visibility check immediately when the page is loaded before any scrolling occur.

It is to my understanding that componentDidMount is when React already rendered an element for the first time, so I wanted to do the check then. However, I was trying to render two ContentSection components, each containing their own check point. The latter check point for unknown reason is positioned higher than it appears on screen during componentDidMount, resulting in my visibility check returning true even though it is not visible. If I refresh the page, its position is correct again and the visibility check is fine.

This problem only seem to occur during the first time when I open up a new tab to load my code, but no longer occurs after a refresh on that tab.

Any idea why?

Comment: What do you mean by `but no longer occurs after a refresh on that tab`. What is the 'refresh' action?